# How to use data from field papers to QGIS

Tags: qgis

I work on Field Papers and I need to get the information from the QR Scan code on the field papers on to QGIS. Can you please share how it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it, Field Papers is "nothing more" than a service that helps you to create GeoTIFs from annotated printed maps. The QR code is only there to allow fieldpapers.org to correctly place your map.

Once you re-upload one of the maps to the website, you can view it as a slippy map and also download it as a geotiff (there is a black button in the lower right corner labeled "Download GeoTiff").

You can then open the downloaded GeoTIFF in QGIS and proceed to work with it just as with every other raster data (e.g. digitize your hand-written stuff, or use it as a base map).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to load it as a GeoTIFF, you could use something like the [TileLayer](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/TileLayerPlugin/) plugin and load the scanned FieldPapers atlas as a TMS service. Here's what the XYZ template looks like:

http://tiles.fieldpapers.org/snapshots/4bwz5g3d/{z}/{x}/{y}.png